# Materials Modeling in Industry

Tags: condensed-matter

This question is primarily targeted to individuals who are working in industries and in the field of materials modeling.

*[Be ambiguous wherever required]*

(i) Please explain your role briefly

(ii) the types of theoretical methods/softwares and calculations that you perform regularly

(iii) How is the perception within your organization on these results.

Comment: +1. But I do worry that some might try to close this because it's 3 questions in one, and it might be considered quite unusual for the StackExchange rules.

Comment: This seems like it would be both too broad and too discussion based. This sort of question would probably work better in the Facebook group for this site, where there isn't as much of an expectation of looking for relatively narrow, objective answers.

Comment: Good point I forgot about the Facebook group. That's where you can ask this type of question without worrying about anyone closing it or downvoting it: https://www.facebook.com/groups/MaterialsModelingStackExchange/

Comment: Writing this question up, I knew it's a discussion oriented question too. But figured I'll still post it just in case - it's good to know the other avenues to discuss this.